# why is this INDEX-MATCH formula better than my repeating IFERROR - VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: indexing, match, vlookup

I was advised to use this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,INDIRECT("'"&INDEX(AK$2:AK$13,MATCH(TRUE,     COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&AK$2:AK$13&"'!A$2:T$200"),A2)>0,0))&"'! A$2:T$200"),17,0)
```

However, because I don't understand it and  I am struggling to apply it to my own worksheet.

My instinct was to use:
    `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,sheetB,A:Q,17,0),IFERROR(vLOOKUP(A2,sheetC,A:Q,17,0),IFERROR...etc`

along each worksheet

My way is simplistic, but seems to work.  am I losing anything by using it (apart from the respect of my code minded colleagues)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree. INDIRECT makes spreadsheets brittle (granted; you're not hardcoding cell references in its arguments so it's not as brittle as it can be.). But it is a *volatile* function which means you can never assert that your workbook is fully calculated.

VLOOKUP is not much better, but both solutions contain it.

I prefer your option.

Comment: Thanks Bathsheba, although i still dont understand the first formula, i can tell my colleague that i rejected it because it was too brittle and volatile, and denied me the assertion that my workbook is fully calculated.  That aught to shut him up!!

Comment: The fact that the first formula is harder to understand is a compelling reason not to use it. Program at 50% of your ability so you can debug at 100%.